# Ruby unescape hex code in string

Tags: ruby, hex, special-characters

Does Ruby have a method to unescape hex codes within a string?

For example:

```
  string = "Plus minus symbol: &#xB1;"
```

How can I print that string with the hex code replaced with the actual character: "±"? I'm looking for a generic solution that works for any hex code.

Comment: I was able to decode the special character using HTMLEntities.new.decode(string).

Thanks @theTinMan!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) to parse the symbol and then add it to your string:

```
require 'nokogiri'

symbol = Nokogiri::HTML.parse("&#xB1;").text
#=> "±"

string = "Plus minus symbol: #{symbol}"
#=> "Plus minus symbol: ±"
```

Comment: Nokogiri is overkill for this.

Comment: @theTinMan It could be, i guess it depends on the scope. But i'll add another option with `CGI`. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: CGI is out of date, and has holes for this so be careful. I'd recommend the solution in the question linked in the close reason.

Comment: @theTinMan Ohh, ok, thanks again. I'll check the linked question.

Comment: Solution is in linked post. My question wasn't about HTML but the htmlentities gem does the trick.